# Android _data' does not exist on getContentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

What might the  cause of getColumnIndexOrThrow that would throw an exception of

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist. Available columns: []

yet if you rename the file and retry again, it works?

```
private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
        };
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int cindex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
                return cursor.getString(cindex);
            }
        }
             catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

the original file comes in the intent of

**content://com.sec.android.app.myfiles.FileProvider/device_storage/Download/myfile.pdf**

yet the renamed file comes in as

**content://0@media/external/file/588**

Comment: So if I simply use uri.getPath() on the original file the path comes back (invalid) as 

```/device_storage/Download/myFile.pdf ```

Which is an invalid path to my file open routine, and yet if  I rename it and try again it comes back with:


 ```/storage/emulated/0/Download/myFile.pdf```

Which opens the file just fine?


Thoughts?

Comment: Anyone have an idea why the MyFiles app has this issue however other explorer apps send the right getData()?

Comment: please explain what you are actually trying to do? what you have done before and expected after. and when this exception thrown.

Comment: I have an activity that handles the opening of a file and registers the type in the manifest so that i can be used to open a file of that type.  In one case the getData() returns as see above one string which does not resove to a valid file path.  Yet if I rename the file in the exteral file exporer and try again, the getData string returned is valid.

Comment: i'v put extra materials to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA` is deprecated and `column '_data'` doesn't exist anymore.

As [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATA) stated

> **This constant was deprecated in API level 29.**
>
> Apps may not have filesystem permissions to directly access this path.
>   Instead of trying
>   to open this path directly, apps should use
>   ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String) to gain access.

### How To use *openFileDescriptor*?

i try to bring examples of 2 different widely use files in across application

### Image Files

```
if(uri==null)return;
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
if(contentResolver==null)return;
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri,"rw");
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
if(fileDescriptor==null)return;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
parcelFileDescriptor.close();
```

There are a lot of examples of how to handle `bitmap`

### Non-Image Files

```
if(uri==null)return;
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
if(contentResolver==null)return;
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri,"rw");
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
if(fileDescriptor==null)return;
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
parcelFileDescriptor.close();
```

There are a lot of examples of how to handle `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`

### Conclusion

There is no sense trying to get `absolute Path` although it isn't necessary unless raising security & privacy issues.Indeed, `Relative path` is enough for working with files and there are `Abstract Representation implementations` between `kernel Mode` and `User Mode` that can Map `Relative Path` to `Absolute Path` and User doesn't need to know.

`openFileDescriptor` is very fast and compatible to all android versions

Comment: is the right way to do this with intent.getData().getPath?  If so the data sent by MyFiles still breaks however other file explorer apps sent the correct info?  This is on a Note10 Plus Running Android 10

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  My issue is, that I have to pass an absolute path string to the library I'm calling and not a descriptor or stream.